# Soft sound strings for Fender bass

Tags: strings, bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, 5-string-bass-guitar

I'm looking for "soft sounding" strings for my five-string Fender bass (American Deluxe V).
Default Fender strings are not for me, unfortunately.  What kind of strings can give me this sound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by soft, you mean less bright, then flat wound strings might be for you. I'd recommend [Thomastik Jazz Flats](http://www.thomastik-infeld.com/johcgi/tho2/TCgi.cgi?Target=list_SetfamilieSubSubs&SetType=Guitar&ID_Setfamilie=20&ID_SetfamilieSub=41&ID_SetfamilieSubSubStaerke=158), a little expensive, but they last a very long time. They sound wonderful, with a kind of throaty, singing voice, with just the right amount of thump, and more sustain than any other brand I tried. They made my cheap accoustic fretless bass sound much more doghousey. On my Fender Precision they sounded like James-Jamerson-meets-Mick-Karn, if that makes any sense. HTH.

Comment: Jazz Flats made my Squier P sound fan-freaking-tastic!  I felt bad about putting strings that cost 2/3 the price of the bass, but SO worth it!